# Pointer Conception

Tags: c++, c

Here i get 4225440 as the address of arr[0]; as it an integer array, the address will be increased by 4, so next one will be 4225444;

now

1. whats happen with those addresses
2. if put manualy one of addresses it shows absurd value from where it comes.

This is the code under discussion

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[10],i,a,*j;
void del(int a);

main()
{
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);

    j=(int*)4225443;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d ",arr[i]);
        printf(" %d ",&arr[i]);
    }

    printf(" %d ",*j);
}
```

Comment: Depends on the processor architecture. That would crash in for example an ARM processor, due to an unaligned access on printing `*j`. And of course, unless we know what is at address `4225443`, it's impossible to say even if it's valid.

Comment: why we can't store the value of arr[1] in 4225441 if arr[0] is in 4225440

Comment: @MatsPetersson note that some ARM processors have support for unaligned access

Comment: @BijooSingh: Because in a machine with byte addressing, one step in address is one byte, typically 8 bits -> only a range of 0..255 or -128..127, which is typically not enough for useful counting/general integer use. In fact, the C and C++ standard requires int to be at least 16 bits. In a machine with "word addressing" (so individual bytes are not addressable uniquely), then it would indeed be possible to have 1 as the difference between two integer addresses.

Comment: still confused. well that means 4 bytes need 4 addresses to store its value .but then so why those addresses actually utilized by other resources..that if it's works in that way those addresses must be accessible with correct value or can't be access  at all.

Comment: it seems that it is time to re-take that class on how data is represented.  and note it the architecture your using has big endian or little endian accessing of multibyte values.

Comment: Violating alignment requirement is basically cheating the processor and compiler.

Comment: When the CPU is accessing a 4-byte quantity, it typically works best if the address is "aligned" properly, which usually means the address is a multiple of the size of the type being accessed (so, any address for a single byte, a multiple of 2 for a 2-byte quantity, and a multiple of 4 for a 4-byte quantity).  If the address is not aligned, depending on the CPU and O/S, you get an error (with core dump, perhaps), or you get slow access (it becomes a system call), or you get moderately fast access (the CPU reads two or more units of memory and extracts what it needs from the mess).

Comment: You are dealing entirely in undefined behaviour here. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 6):

```
j=(int*)4225443;
/* ... */
printf(" %d ",*j);
```

C has its word to say:

> (C11, 6.3.2.3p5) "An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation."

In your case you can add to that you are also violating aliasing rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
most of the CPUs that we use today have either
a 32bit or 64 bit wide bus between the CPU and the memory.

Lets use the 32 bit wide bus for demonstration purposes..

in general, each memory access will be to read (or write) 32 bits,
where the first address of that 32 bits will be an address
that is evenly divisible by 32.

In such a architecture, a 'int' will start on a address 
that is evenly divisible by 32 and be 4 bytes (32bits) long.

in general, when the address of 'something' is NOT 
on a 32 bit address boundary 
(I.E. the address is not evenly divisible by 32) 
then the CPU will:
for read, 
read the whole 32 bits from memory, 
starting at the 32 bit boundary,     
then, within the CPU, 
using the registers and the logic and math operations, 
extract the desired byte.
for write, 
read the whole 32 bits from memory,  
starting at the 32 bit boundary,
then, within the CPU, 
using the registers and logic and math operations, 
modify the desired byte, 
then write the whole 32 bits to memory

In other words, 
accessing memory other than on 32bit boundarys is SLOW.

Unfortunately some CPUs, 
if requested to read/write some value to/from memory
at other than a 32 bit boundary will raise a bus error.

regarding the 'unbelievable' value of the int 
when the second byte of the int is modified...

A int (lets use a little endian architecture) is 4 bytes, 
aligned on a 32 bit boundary 
(I.E. the lowest address of the int is on a 32 bit boundary.)

Lets, for example say the int contains '5' 
then its' representation in memory is 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05

Then the second byte (address of the int+1) is set to some value,
 for example, say 3,  
Then the int contains 0x000, 0x03, 0x00, 0x05

now, when that int is printed, it will display: 196613

Note: the order of the bytes in memory is somewhat different 
      for a big endian architecture.
```

Answer (score -2):

It will print value, located in address 4225443, if value exists, otherwise it will produce memory violation exception.

Comment: I think you mean, if the access to that memory address is allowed. No memory address has a holds a value that does not exist.

Comment: not even close.  and the code is not trying to print the contents of 4225443.

Comment: @user3629249: the code does other things too, but why do you say it is not trying to print the contents of 4225443?